# Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) No matching user found (code 100, subcode 2018001)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-rest-api, facebook-messages

Im using restfb api for connecting facebook client
and im trying to send message to facebook user(recipient) from facebook Page.

But it is throwing error:
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) No matching user found (code 100, subcode 2018001)

and using this error code and subcode i found that recipient id i passed is wrong. recipient id i passed is generated by Graph API Explorer which returns as shown below and i used that id for recipient id 
{
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "name": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
}

so can anyone tell me how to generate recipient id of user.

Comment: You can not send messages to arbitrary users, you can only _respond_ to the messages they send your page in the first place. (And when you read those messages, you _get_ the user id from there.)

Comment: ok, ill try by texting from user

Comment: can u send me procedure to get user id as you told above

Comment: When the user send you a message you will get the user ID.